# Is storing an entity tag for If-None-Mach header in Android shared preferences a good idea?

Tags: android, http

Since android doesn't have built-in If-None-Match header support I plan to store the entity tag and add corresponding header manually.

I shared preference applicable for that or there is a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since I haven't found any recommendation regarding If-None-Match header support I ended up utilising SharedPreferences. Have not discovered any pitfalls with this technic yet.

Comment: How did you end up using it in SharedPrefs? info.commit?